# SQL server two indexed columns have different speed performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

I have a table which have two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE #history(
    Today        INT    NOT NULL,
    LastDay      INT    NOT NULL
           PRIMARY KEY(Today, LastDay))
```

I also created a nonclustered index:

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX #history_IX1 ON #history(LastDay)
```

However, when I join table using column Today, the performance would be way more faster than using column LastDay, like 20s vs 4s.

I think the problem may be caused by the column LastDay hasn't properly indexed. I also use SQL hint to force indexing, the results are same.

Here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO anytable(
       anycolumn)
SELECT m.anycolumn
FROM   AMillionTable m
       INNER JOIN #history h
               ON h.Today  = m.day

m.day also indexed.
Same query, when change h.Today to h.LastDay, the process speed significantly drops.
```

Any solutions for this problem?

Comment: You should only use hints when you are absolutely certain there is no other way. When you use hints you are telling the sql engine that you know more about optimization of the query than the engine does. Your question is not really very clear but it seems that you could get a lot of information from this set of articles that covers indexing from a basic level to a pretty deep dive. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/

Comment: Could you post the explain plans from the two queries?

Comment: @PeterSmith I have added an example, hope that could explain the scenario.

Comment: The explains would show what is going on in much greater detail.  It would show if it is hitting the index (or not), whether it's an index seek or scan, rows to be fetched, cost, and so on. Sql server often shows an index suggestion if it can't find a good index for the plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal, because they are 2 different indexes CLUSTERED vs NONCLUSTERED. When you join using the Today column, the CLUSTERED index will be used. Extra work is needed for the NONCLUSTERED index.

You can find more information here [Link](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/clustered-vs-non-clustered-index/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm aware of that the nonclustered index is slower than clustered index. But even I switch the order in primary keys `PRIMARY KEY(LastDay, Today)`, and create a nonclustered index on Today, the performance is still low on LastDay column.